# A combinatorial problem concerned with logic circuits

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Consider a logic circuit with two-bit gates only. The *length* of each gate is the number of bit lines that the gate crosses. How hard is to compute the maximum length for a given circuit? Notice that two circuits are, say, *isomorphic*, if they differ only up to a permutation of the bit lines. Notice that there are clearly $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ bit lines.

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Is this supposed to resemble one side of a printed circuit board?  Most circuit layouts use more than one layer.

Comment: Are the gates rectangles arrayed in the plane? If so, perhaps your problem is reducible to computing the crossing number of a graph, which (as you likely know) is NP-hard, even for cubic graphs.

Comment: Indeed the circuit is a graph drawn on the plane with horizontal and vertical edges: the horizontal edges are segments of the bit lines; the vertical edges are the gates. To minimize the length we can only permute the bit lines. Surely the parameter of the question is the crossing number of this graph. However, I am not sure whether it is easy to compute it given the special structure.

Comment: Thanks for the picture.  I had a completely different idea of gate.  I think of sorting networks when I see your picture.  Perhaps that literature might have an answer for you.  My guess is that it is as hard as graph isomorphism.

Comment: Try this idea: see if you can reduce Independent Set to this problem.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: I have modified the title and included the term "crossing number". I hope now the context of the question is clearer.

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly the crossing number? There seems to be an implicit assumption that if you can embed a graph in the plane with $k$ crossings, then you can also do it in a "straight" way. Or is such a fact known?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: The only crossings in the graph are given by the gates crossing the bit lines. Of course, the graph is drawn in the plane in a very special way. We can only permute the bit lines in order to change the number of crossings, but nothing else.

Comment: A clarification: do you want to minimize the sum of the lengths of the gates, or minimize the maximum length? For example if  - in the left picture above - the lines connected are $(1,4),(1,3)$, what is the "cost" of that arrangement? Is it higher (worst) than the $(1,4),(1,2)$ arrangement?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: The maximum length. Honestly, I am not sure whether the two problems that you mention are really different. It may well be. In the example that you give, let us consider the circuit ((1,4),(1,3)). If we swap the lines 1 and 3, we obtain ((3,4),(1,3)). Now, if we swap the lines 1 and 2 (these are 2 and 3 in the new arrangement), we obtain ((3,4),(2,3)). So, the maximum length of the circuit ((1,4),(1,3)) is 1 since 4-3=1 and 3-2=1. The permutation that we used is 2314. The other example is exactly the one in the fig and the max length is again 1. In fact it's the same circuit.

Comment: re bounty assigned for proof of NP completeness: huh? the bandwidth problem is already proven NP complete. the proof/ref is surely on the wiki page. oh was the bounty assigned before the 1st answer by suresh? (ok)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to find a permutation of the bit lines so the maximum gate "length" is as small as possible. This is called the [bandwidth problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth):

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ find a permutation $\pi : V \rightarrow [1 \ldots n]$ such that $$\max_{(i,j) \in E} |\pi(i) - \pi(j)|$$ is minimized.

The wikipedia article has more information on the complexity (it's NP-hard and APX-hard) and algorithms. The bandwidth problem is interesting also because it was used to introduce the idea of volume-respecting embeddings.

Comment: Then this is the answer! Thank you!